# TypeError: this.client.blockedFromCommand.delete is not a function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

this.client.blockedFromCommand.delete('411621794131476480') whenever i use this code

TypeError: this.client.blockedFromCommand.delete is not a function

i get this error pls help

```
this.blockedFromCommand = [];
this.commandBlock = new Map();
```

Comment: Arrays (`[]`) don't have a `delete()` method

Comment: so how can i delete a value

Comment: I'd probably use a map, like `this.blockedFromCommand = new Map()`, for this as well. `Map#delete()` should be faster then `Array#filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays do not have a [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/delete) method ([sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) however do). Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead:

```js
let newArray = this.client.blockedFromCommand.filter(e => e !=== "411621794131476480");
```